# Как правильно настроить редирект в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Страница логина - главная страница сайта. После логина происходит редирект на страницу с диалогами('/user'). Но если обновить страницу с диалогами, то на долю секунды показывается страница логина, меняется стейт в редаксе и соответственно выполняется редирект.
Выглядит вот так:

```
const isAuth = useSelector(state => state.user.auth)

return isAuth ? <Redirect to='/user' />  : <Login />
```

Думал показывать прелоадер, но я не могу подставить его вместо компонента логина, потому что получается неверное условие:

```
const isAuth = useSelector(state => state.user.auth)
if(isAuth) <Loader />
return isAuth ? <Redirect to='/user' />  : <Login />
```

Как правильно организовать роутинг, чтобы после входа вместо "мигающего" компонента логина при перезагрузке страницы был прелоадер либо просто сделать без редиректа?

Проект пишется для себя, поэтому вот [Github](https://github.com/alex-borovikov/project_chat__react-node/tree/development/client);

Редирект внутри компонента Login -> src/components/Auth/Login/Login.jsx

Comment: Можешь попробовать хранить состояние авторизации в ```localStorage``` Или добавить состояние загрузки, которое будет отображать вместо всего документа ```preloader```. Состояние можно прописать в промежуточный обработчик который работает примерно так же как и ```thunk```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать подобный Middleware:

```
const loaderMiddlewate =
        ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
        (next) =>
        (action) => {
                const { helpers } = getState()
                if (
                        helpers.loader &&
                        action.type !== DISABLED_LOADER &&
                        action.type !== TOGGLE_LOADER
                ) {
                        dispatch(disabledLoader())
                }
                return next(action)
        }
```

Перед каждым запросом изменять состояние `preloader`. Таково мое решение, других пока не видел